# Order list by List<int> property

Tags: linq, list, int

I need to order my list by points, then by positions. How can I order my list by the Positions List property?

```
public class Sailor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public List<int> Positions { get; set; }

    public Sailor(string name, int points, List<int> positions)
    {
        Name = name;
        Points = points;
        Positions = positions;
    }
}

var sailors = new List<Sailor>
                    {
                        new Sailor("Carl", 20, new List<int> { 2, 2, 4, 1, 1 }),
                        new Sailor("Paul", 10, new List<int> { 4, 5, 3, 2, 5 }),
                        new Sailor("Anna", 20, new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 3, 4 }),
                        new Sailor("Lisa", 11, new List<int> { 3, 4, 5, 5, 2 }),
                        new Sailor("Otto", 11, new List<int> { 5, 3, 2, 4, 3 })
                    };

foreach (var sailor in sailors)
{
    sailor.Positions.Sort();
}

var orderedListOfSailors = sailors.OrderByDescending(x => x.Points);
```

This gives me:

```
Carl, Anna, Lisa, Otto, Paul
```

What I want it to be:

```
Anna, Carl, Otto, Lisa, Paul
```

Why? Because Anna have 3 first places,  Carl have 2. Otto have 2, 3, 3, Lisa have 2, 3, 4.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by using lexicographical odering on instances of `Sailor`; either you could implement a custom comparator for `Sailor` or use the `ThenBy` extension method.

Answer (score 0):

After ordering them by `Points`, order them again by the number of places.

```
var orderedListOfSailors = sailors
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Points)
                        .ThenByDescending(x => x.Positions.Count(y => y == 1))
                        .ThenByDescending(x => x.Positions.Count(y => y == 2))
                        .ThenByDescending(x => x.Positions.Count(y => y == 3))
                        .ThenByDescending(x => x.Positions.Count(y => y == 4));
```